# how to dynamically find the attributes of a html link using Jquery and tokenize the ref attribute by comma?

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Imagine i have a list of fruit names being dynamically populated and the codes generated by php is as follows

```
<div id="fruit_list">
  <ol>
    <li>Apple <a id='1' ref='red'>Delete</a></li>
    <li>Pear <a href id='2' ref='green'>Delete</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I want to do a ajax delete where when the user clicks delete link, under the fruit_list div and while onclick of the delete link, i want to know the attributes id and ref of the clicked link. Upon knowing attributes, how could i explode it in jQuery so that the ref can be seperated by the comma.

Can you suggest an approch if i am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't heard of an ref attribute. And you shouldn't make up your own. You could use the data attribute for it (data-ref=value).

Or you could do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/gmrcn/6/

HTML

```
<div id="fruit_list">
  <ol>
    <li>Apple <a href="#1" class="delete" id='red'>Delete</a></li>
    <li>Pear <a href="#2" class="delete" id='green'>Delete</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('a.delete').click( function() {
    //get fruitname and id
    var fruit = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = $(this).attr('href').replace("#","");

    //send with ajax, to your serverscript
    $.post('yourdeletescript.php', {id:id, fruit:fruit} , function(data) {
         //remove LI of the deleted 
         $('#'+fruit).parent().remove();
    });

    //disable default link action
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#fruit_list a').bind('click', function (evt) {
  console.log(
    /*the element id*/
    $(this).attr('id'),

    /*the element attribute ref, splitted by ,*/
    $(this).attr('ref').split(/,/)
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I will try and flag it answered if it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what exactly you are asking. But i would implement delete function as follows.

```
$('div#fruit_list ol li a').click(function(){ //adding click event to all delete links
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //getting value of id attribute of the clicked link
  var ref= $(this).attr('ref');//getting value of ref attribute of the clicked link
  $.post('/script',{id:id, ref:ref},function(){ // send id and ref to delete script
    $('#'+id).parent().remove();//remove the corresponding li on success
  });
})
```

Comment: This is what i am asking. But i want to select #fruit_list link as there maybe many other modules and stuffs.